# XPath to count the child nodes based on complex filter

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML in the following format:

```
<ComRequest>
  <root lineId="1" creator="jumnix">
    <component lineId="101">
        <compLine lineId="1001">1</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1002">2</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1003">3</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1004">4</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1005">5</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1006">6</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1007">7</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1008">8</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1009">9</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1010">10</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1011">11</compLine>
    </component>
    <component lineId="102">
        <compLine lineId="1012">12</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1013">13</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1014">14</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1015">15</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1016">16</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1017">17</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1018">18</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1019">19</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1020">20</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1021">21</compLine>
        <compLine lineId="1022">22</compLine>
    </component>
  </root>
</ComRequest>
```

I have a requirement to get the count of the 'component' nodes that have more than 10 'compLine' elements. Till now I have the following XPath query -

```
count(//*[local-name()='ComRequest']/*[local-name()='root']/*[local-name()='component']/*[local-name()='compLine' and count(self) gt 10])
```

But this does not work (gives a '0' result). Any help in getting this resolved is appreciated.

Comment: anytime. wish I could help more with a solution. cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about `count(//ComRequest/root/component[count(compLine)>10])` ?

Comment: That does not work unfortunately. I have to use the 'local-name()' in the XPath as the gateway where I am supposed to configure this does not handle the XML nodes if is has any attributes.

Comment: @Vinnie, how about `count(//*[local-name()='ComRequest']/*[local-name()='root']/*[local-name()='component'][count(*) > 10])` ?

Comment: Appears that there was some issue with the XSLT processor on the gateway. Now its resolved and the XPath expression evaluates perfectly. 
Thanks a lot for your help Bala.

Comment: Here is what the gateway SME change the XPath to-    count(//*[local-name()='ComRequest]/*[local-name()='root']/*[local-name()='component'][count(*[local-name()='compLine') > 10])

Answer (score 2):

@Bala-R (+1) is correctly evaluated using a compliant XSLT 1.0 processor (Saxon):

```
count(//ComRequest/root/component[count(compLine)>10])
```

or, either

```
count(/*/*/*[count(compLine)>10])
```

Otherwise something is going bad in your tests, your context (different from the one provided in the question) or your xpath evaluator.

Comment: the example works if I remove the node attributes. But with the attributes, the result is coming as '0'. I have taken this up with the team and waiting for them to response.

Comment: As you expected, there was some problem at the XSLT processer end. Now it works fine. Thanks a lot for your time and help - appreciate it.