# counting child nodes using XPATH

Tags: xpath

I have following XML

```
<orderList>
    <orderInfo orderId="xyz" returnCode="Pending" />
    <orderInfo orderId="yzz" returnCode="Shipped">
        <orderDetail shipped-date="xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx">
            <order>
               ....
            </order>
        </orderDetail>
    </orderInfo>
</orderList>
```

I want to count # of order under each orderDetail item ...

I tried this link ([XPath to count the child nodes based on complex filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270859/xpath-to-count-the-child-nodes-based-on-complex-filter)) but it didn't help

I came up with this path

`count(//orderList/orderInfo/orderDetail[count(order)])`

Comment: What language do you use to wrap around XPath? You need something like `foreach //orderList/orderInfo/orderDetail give count(order)`

Comment: To clarify, you want a list of numbers as the result – one for each `orderDetail`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to count *all* `order` elements in the `orderList/orderInfo/orderDetail` nodes (ignoring their current context), then you could use:

```
count(//orderList/orderInfo/orderDetail/order)
```

If you want to count the number of orders *for a specific* `orderDetail`, then you should use a predicate to select *which* `orderDetail` you want:

```
count(//orderList/orderInfo/orderDetail[@shipped-date="xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx"]/order)
```

Unless you are using XPath 2.0 or a greater version, you won't be able to return a collection of results with a single expression. But you can select all `orderDetail` elements (`//orderList/orderInfo/orderDetail`), iterate through them and count the order elements in the current context, or set the predicate value as a variable to select a specific `orderDetail`.

Comment: Since this is the first Google result for "count children xpath", I'll also note that `count(*)` counts all (direct) child nodes