# Xpath: Number of elements "abc" whose parent`s parent contains 1 "abc" element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Let`s say I have the following XML:

```
<elementList id="1">
    <everything>
        <owned>no</owned>
    </everything>
    <elementList id="2">
        <allElements>
            <owned>no</owned>
        </allElements>
        <officeList id="3">
            <room>
                <owned>no</owned>
            </room>
            <furniture>
                <owned>yes</owned>
            </furniture>
        </officeList>
    </elementList>
    <transportation>
        <allCarsOwned>
            <owned>yes</owned>
        </allCarsOwned>
        <cars id="4">
            <truck>
                <owned>yes</owned>
            </truck>
            <motorcycle>
                <owned>yes</owned>
            </motorcycle>
            <familyCar>
                <owned>yes</owned>
            </familyCar>
        </cars>
    </transportation>
</elementList>
```

I would like to create an XSLT which counts the "owned" elements, whatever name they have, and also the elements which are not owned, without counting the ancestor lists (composite elements) which include contain other elements (only count the terminal elements which contain a child ").

For instance, the "owned" elements are:

```
furniture, truck, motorcycle, familyCar
```

Likewise, the "not owned" elements are:

```
room
```

The following elements should not be included in any list:

```
everything, allElements, allCarsOwned
```

The names may vary a lot, there is no rule, I can`t identify them by name.

Currently I count everything that is owned and that is not owned like this:

```
    <xsl:variable name="ownedStuff" select="count(//doc:owned[text()='yes'])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="notOwnedStuff" select="count(//doc:owned[text()='no'])"/>
```

but this gives me false counts.

I would rather use the following expression:

```
count(//doc:owned[text()='whatever'] and count(//doc:owned::parent::parent:://doc:owned) lt 2)
```

or something.. I don`t really get it.

Someone can help me, please?

```
.
.
.
```

Plot change: Would it be ***VERY*** difficult to have the whole line of IDs and parent node names for each owned / not owned node?

Thank you all!

Comment: Note: the lists do not necessarrily have all parameters, some are missing ID, some have other parameters... it`s very messed up

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to count the elements who:

1. have a child `owned` whose value = "yes"; and
2. do not have a "nephew" other than `owned`

-

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//*[owned='yes' and not(../*/*[not(self::owned)])])"/>
```

---

I am afraid I didn't understand this part:

> Plot change: Would it be VERY difficult to have the whole line of IDs
>   and parent node names for each owned / not owned node?

Comment: How do you format the comments ?!?!?!?!

I would like to count all the "terminal elements" (elements which do not contain other elements) either owned or not owned.

    .

The part with "plot change" referrs to not simply having these two lists:

    Owned: furniture, truck, motorcycle, familyCar

    Not owned: room

But having each element as:

    Owned: elementList->elementList->furniture, elementList->transportation->cars->truck, elementList->transportation->cars->motorcycle, elementList->transportation->cars->familyCar

    Not owned: elementList->elementList->room

Comment: @ro0ter "*How do you format the comments ?!?!?!*" You don't; you edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have found both solutions by myself, thanks to Google and free time!

First I would like to thank @BallaR for the answer to another question (on stackoverflow.com):

> [XPath to count the child nodes based on complex filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270859/xpath-to-count-the-child-nodes-based-on-complex-filter)

His answer for the question was:

```
count(//ComRequest/root/component[count(compLine)>10])
```

and made me consider using complex selects, which did the trick!!! Thank god such thinkgs are possible... It's been more than 5 years since I have worked with XSLT, can't believe I have forgot so fast.

The solution to counting nodes with complex filter is:

```
count(//doc:owned[text()='whatever' and count(../..//doc:owned[text()='whatever']) lt 2])
```

Now I must see if I get to the point of enumerating all ancestors of each owned element.

```
.
.
.
```

Indeed, it is possible to also get the names of all ancestors of "whatever" owned nodes (usually "not" owned in my case):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//doc:owned[text()='whatever' and count(../..//doc:owned[text()='whatever']) lt 2]">
    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>. 
    <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>
    <xsl:if test="../@Id">
        (#<xsl:value-of select="../@Id"/>)
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:call-template name="while">
        <xsl:with-param name="parentNode" select="../.."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template name="while">
    <xsl:param name="parentNode"/>
    <xsl:if test="name($parentNode) != ''"> <!-- to avoid root and document nodes -->
        [<xsl:value-of select="name($parentNode)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$parentNode/../@Id">
            (#<xsl:value-of select="$parentNode/../@Id"/>)
        </xsl:if>]
        <xsl:if test="$parentNode/..">
            <xsl:call-template name="while">
                <xsl:with-param name="parentNode" select="$parentNode/.."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I am so glad XSLT exists :)

Regards to everyone!